# I want to extract particular data from this json file

Tags: flutter, dart

//This is json file

```
"Countries":[{"ID":"cf898a52-4040-47c3-8da5-d54ef938d735","Country":"Afghanistan","CountryCode":"AF","Slug":"afghanistan","NewConfirmed":0,"TotalConfirmed":162111,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":7408,"NewRecovered":0,"TotalRecovered":0,"Date":"2022-01-31T10:35:08.408Z","Premium":{}},
{"ID":"119f471e-8cdc-42a5-8dd3-7c160b47ebf1","Country":"Albania","CountryCode":"AL","Slug":"albania","NewConfirmed":0,"TotalConfirmed":255741,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":3334,"NewRecovered":0,"TotalRecovered":0,"Date":"2022-01-31T10:35:08.408Z","Premium":{}},
{"ID":"c4a92ecf-cfaa-4431-a5f9-e86f49dcc7fd","Country":"Algeria","CountryCode":"DZ","Slug":"algeria","NewConfirmed":0,"TotalConfirmed":250774,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":6566,"NewRecovered":0,"TotalRecovered":0,"Date":"2022-01-31T10:35:08.408Z","Premium":{}},
{"ID":"ae65f122-8ee0-4a33-9d73-85db5d352474","Country":"Andorra","CountryCode":"AD","Slug":"andorra","NewConfirmed":0,"TotalConfirmed":35556,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":145,"NewRecovered":0,"TotalRecovered":0,"Date":"2022-01-31T10:35:08.408Z","Premium":{}},
{"ID":"7c676fc0-f2a5-49a7-9512-036c72e6e197","Country":"Angola","CountryCode":"AO","Slug":"angola","NewConfirmed":0,"TotalConfirmed":98076,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":1895,"NewRecovered":0,"TotalRecovered":0,"Date":"2022-01-31T10:35:08.408Z","Premium":{}},
{"ID":"6fd9fc92-4a29-4503-a721-3003c08be8b8","Country":"Antigua and Barbuda","CountryCode":"AG","Slug":"antigua-and-barbuda","NewConfirmed":0,"TotalConfirmed":6558,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":127,"NewRecovered":0,"TotalRecovered":0,"Date":"2022-01-31T10:35:08.408Z","Premium":{}}],
```

//I want the value of TotalConfirmed of Angola Country

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
void main() {
  var map = {
    "Countries":[{"ID":"334d3cba-c305-4bd6-8da1-97bdc8273eec",
      "Country":"USA",
                      "Date":"2022-01-30T07:14:34.603Z","Premium":{}}]};
  
  print(map);
  //Output
  /*
    {Countries: [{ID: 334d3cba-c305-4bd6-8da1-97bdc8273eec, Country: USA, Date: 2022-01-30T07:14:34.603Z, Premium: {}}]}
   */
  
  print(map["Countries"]![0]['Country']);

}
```

DartPad Example:-

[image]